# Replace letters in a text using symbols through CMD

Tags: text, replace, cmd

I need some help in using the CMD. I am an amateur programmer so please be gentle with technical terms! However, I think that what I need is quite simple for a programmer!

I am developing a simple text encode/decode bot (with WinAutomation software) that will run in a very slow MS Windows PC. I use my own encoding/decoding method for years so I am not interested in using a ready-made solution.
I want to be able to replace any letter in any text (as a variable) with symbols and vice versa using the command line.

Example:
“a” will be “[?]”
“b” will be “[*]”
“c” will be “[/]”

Vice versa

“[?]” will be “a”
“[*]” will be “b”
Etc

I am currently using a loop to do the 130 letter replacements. Loop is executed very fast and causes CPU and memory overload in  slow PC. From the other hand, If I place a waiting action at the end of the loop (1 sec minimum), the replacements will finish in 130 seconds. This is time wasting!

I need a ONE LINE code in order to make the replacements at once through CMD.
A programmer suggested me the piece of code below that seems to work but it is not one line

```
SET _test=12345abcabc
SET _result=%_test:ab=xy%
SET _result=%_result:1=2%
```

How can I convert it in one line? I have tried && and || but I am doing something wrong!

Below I have uploaded an image from WinAutomation’s Run Command Window. You can view it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCkaR.jpg.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line. ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION needs to be set. The code before and after the one (1) line is just to ensure that the variables are set to nothing and show that they are set to nothing.

```
C:>type and.bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "_test="
SET "_result="
ECHO _test is %_test%, _result is %_result%

REM Here is the one (1) line.

SET "_test=12345abcabc" && SET "_result=!_test:ab=xy!" && SET "_result=!_result:1=2%!

ECHO _test is %_test%, _result is %_result%
```

Here is a result from running the script.

```
C:>CALL and.bat
_test is , _result is
_test is 12345abcabc, _result is 22345xycxyc
```

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for replying. It seems that I do something wrong!
I have uploaded the cmd screen for you to see!
https://imgur.com/wyxJSVX

Comment: By the way, I am also using a replacement that is [==]. For example, c=[==] or d=[“].
I run the script through a bat file and I get some symbols inside the replacement.
I get [Β©] instread of just  [©]

Comment: Images can be put into SO. Please edit the question.